# C# Generic Type Parameter Sharing across classes

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance

Suppose you have the following Generic class heirarchy:

```
public abstract class GenericBase<T>
{
    T SomeProperty{ get; set; }
}

public class Foo<T>
{
    T SomeProperty{ get; set; }
}

public abstract class GenericChild<T> : GenericBase<T>
{
    // ...

    public bool DoSomething(Foo<T> foo)
    {
        // This is invalid:
        return SomeProperty == foo.SomeProperty;
    }
}
```

The equality check in the DoSomething method won't compile. It produces the following error:

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
```

If it's releveant, these classes are in separate files. What's the best workaround to allow this kind of equality comparison? Is there some kind of pattern or something to allow this in C#?

**Update:**

A few of the answers suggest using a:

```
where T : SomeClass
```

Unfortunately, very often T will be a primitive type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public abstract class GenericBase<T>
    where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    public T SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Foo<T>
{
    public T SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public abstract class GenericChild<T> : GenericBase<T>
    where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    // ... 

    public bool DoSomething(Foo<T> foo)
    {
        // This is valid: 
        return SomeProperty.Equals(foo.SomeProperty);
    }
}
```

C# does not know if == can be applied to T.

Comment: What is the added benefit of implementing IEquatable? The 'object.Equals' method works without it...

Comment: If you are worried about performance (as you wrote in comment to first answer), implementing IEquatable will give you strongly-typed solution (no boxing or casting will be used)

Comment: It forces you to implement IEquatable<T> in the type supplied for T. If you forget to override Object.Equals in one of your classes, then reference equality will be used!

Answer (score 8):

`==` is not generically applicable for all types. It can only be used *if* T is constrained to a type that supports it, such as `where T : class`. However, you would probably be better served using the `Equals` method.

```
return SomeProperty.Equals(foo.SomeProperty);
```

With the applicable null checking applied.

Comment: This get's things compiling. However, what if DoSomething is processor intensive? I'm worried that boxing will negatively impact performance?

Comment: Boxing will be an issue if the type T is a struct *and* it does not override Equals. If the T provides its own Equals implementation, this will not be an issue. You'll simply have to measure to see if this is a performance problem. You could also constrain the T to reference types. But I'd be willing to believe that if DoSomething is processor intensive, those things (not boxing) will be your performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, you have to hint which type T is of.

For example:

```
public abstract class GenericBase<T> where T : MyClass
{
    T SomeProperty{ get; set; }
}

public class Foo<T> where T : MyClass
{
    T SomeProperty{ get; set; }
}

public abstract class GenericChild<T> : GenericBase<T> where T : MyClass
{
}
```

In your MyClass class you could implement the IEquatable interface, so you can do `SomeProperty.Equals(foo.SomeProperty)`

If you do not add the where constraint, you still could use the object.Equals

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare objects of type T, you can use IEqualityComparer interface (compares to given objects of given type) or force T to implement IEquatable (allows object to be compared with object of type T)